# Column Width overlapping chatter from my related list

Tags: related-list

My related list is suddenly overlapping the chatter side. Could someone please help me fix it

[image]

Comment: Is "your" related list an Aura (e.g. lightning:listView) or LWC component? Or is this a Salesforce standard list?